# Python 2.5.2 script that add "The function starts here" to all the functions of the files of a directory

Tags: python, regex

i would like to replace the lines

`function *{`

by

```
function *{echo "The function starts here."
```

where * is what ever.

Any idea how to do that in Python?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Is `*` really "whatever"? Can it contain "{" itself? (This makes a difference in how complicated the regex needs to be.)

Comment: It's true. No, '*' will not contain '{'.

Answer (score 3):

```
re.compile(r'(^function .*{)', re.M).sub(r'\1echo "The function starts here."', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

if all your scripts are "well coded",

```
import fileinput,os
root="/path"
path=os.path.join(root,"mydir")
os.chdir(path)
for file in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith(".txt"): # do for txt files
        for line in fileinput.FileInput(file,inplace=1):
            line=line.rstrip()
            if "function" in line and "{" in line:                     
                 s=line.split("{")
                 s.insert(1,'{echo "The function starts here."')
                 line=' '.join(s)
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a regular expression replace to the text. The module you are looking for is `re`.